# asp.net MVC and RESTful routing, rails-style. Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there any way to get truly restful routing working in MVC, just like the rails dudes have? I 'm talking about nested urls like `/bands/metallica/albums/killemall/track/4`

The only library that I found to be useful is Steve Hodgkiss' [Restful routing](http://stevehodgkiss.com/2009/10/11/restful-routes-for-asp-net-mvc.html). It seems though a bit risky to base my whole project's routing on this guy's pet-project.

What say you MVC veterans?

Comment: Ain't it a little soon to have MVC "veterans" around? :)

Comment: Yes of course it is. But everything is possible when you're in the software engineering world!

Comment: Well, they were hiring positions requiring 3 years of C# experience. In 2002. I think that limited your hiring pool to Anders . . .

Comment: If it's open source (which it is) and it works (which it does) what's the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure:

```
routes.MapRoute("IwannaBeLikeTheCoolRailsKids",
                "bands/{bandName}/albums/{albumName}/tracks/{trackNumber}",
                new { controller = "Bands",
                action = "ByTrack" 
               });
```

Then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult ByTrack(string bandName, string albumName, int trackNumber)
```

Easy peasie.

Comment: Man, you wrote alb**l**um all over the place! :)

Comment: How would you handle this url?  /bands/metallica/albums/killemall/track/the-four-horsemen

Comment: without losing the int track url functionality

Comment: Spelling wasn't my strong suit. As for the second part, there isn't a way to remove the track number from the URL and still use it as a parameter. Rather, what you'd need to do is make it so you could find the song by a url slug field.

Comment: Like this? /bands/metallica/albums/killemall/track/4/the-four-horsemen

What would the method signature look like for that?

Comment: Maybe you want to ask your own question . . .

Comment: So you think that there's no merit in the approach implemented by Steve Hodgkiss? Any kind of RESTful route can be handled by adding more specific routes to the default MVC routing engine?

Comment: Nah, I think it is a great approach in some cases, was really answering the question about how to do custom routing in general in .NET MVC.

Comment: The problem with this approach is what do you do when the entities themselves are not hierarchical. Meaning that the track number is really a unique key for a song in the database.what do you do if the user changes the url to a different album name and what not, but keeps the last ID of the song the same? do you serve the song-detail page, or do you show a 404?

And how do you handle that in your controllers in a general fashion?

Comment: My thought is anyone who manually changes the url to try and find a result deserves a 404 if the there is nothing there. Why write several hours of extra code to accommodate someone who is too lazy to go through your UI to find what they are looking for. I agree, url's need to be user friendly, but don't break your back thinking and coding routes for someone who is tinkering with your urls outside of the UI.

Comment: Yes defining manually all possible path configuraions is certainly possible, but it gets really messy and unmaintainable very quickly, as the amount of possible permutations grows...

Comment: @Roland : true, but my experience is you need to do this for a few critical paths, in many cases you can use more generic routes.